# Variable Tension in the string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

A body of mass $m$ is hanging with a string having linear mass density $\lambda$. What is the tension at point $A$ as shown in the figure.

[image: Sketch]

I am aware of the scenarios in which string is considered massless and all the tension is used for the hanging mass. Here however $\lambda$ is provided for the string so the tension at various points is unequal. How to go about solving such questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the system hanging from the support into two parts. The part including the block and the string  of length $L-y$ forms the lower part and the rest, forms the upper part. Considering the lower part, the tension at point A must balance the entire weight of the lower part if the system is to be stable ad static. Therefore the tension will be equal to the combined weight of the block $m$ and the weight of the string below point A which is $\lambda(L-y)g$ since the $\lambda$ is nothing but mass per unit length which when multiplied by the length gives mass of that length. If the $\lambda$ is given variable, as a function of height, you solve it the same way by dividing into two parts and then to solve for the weight of the string in the lower part instead of simple multiplication you will have to integrate and find the weight but the process remains essentially the same.
Answer=$mg+\lambda(L-y)g$

Comment: Now suppose that $\lambda$ depends on $m$  and take $g=\frac{GM}{(z+R)^2}$ so the problem will be more challenging...

Comment: @metacompactness Quite difficult. The integral that needs to be solved will get quite a bit complicated even if the $\lambda$ depends elementarily on $m$.